# Ubuntu 19.10 No Wifi Adapter Found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

Everyone

so I have been a windows user previously and finally decided to enter the open source  world of Linux and successfully have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my Lenovo Ideapad e21-25. But since the installation I am not able to use wifi, it says no wifi adapter found. I have search for solution on the internet, tried different ways to fix this but none of them worked for me. Here I am giving the output of "sudo lshw -c NETWORK" commond:

*-network UNCLAIMED

```
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 31
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
```

It shows the adapter on unclaimed network section and here another output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list" command:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

And Output of " dmesg | grep ath " command:

```
[    6.096141] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:4: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   14.667054] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to iomap BAR0
[   14.667101] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to claim device: -5
[   14.667198] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

I've also update and upgrade the system with "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade". But still the Wifi isn't working. If there's any solution available please help with the sol to fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just edit the question with the command you asked for. Please take a look and give me a solution if available

Comment: OK. Please add output of `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: it is some kernel problem. Start with updating the system.

Comment: @Pilot6 Okay... But how do I do that ? I am a newbie sir

Comment: Connect to internet using Ethernet or your phone connected to USB and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sir, I have updated the system and reboot it as you said but still wifi isn't working

Comment: I can suggest reporting a bug. Run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow the directions.

Comment: Okay thank you sir